# Preciso de uma função para adicionar <br> em certas condições

Tags: php, javascript, css

Quero uma função que adicione a tag `<br>` quando o texto não tenha espaçamentos,
eu fiz um Fiddle com o problema: https://jsfiddle.net/sc290ssn/.
Essa função pode ser feita em JavaScript ou PHP.

```
<div class="post">
    <p>kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</p>
</div>
<h3>Queria uma função que deixe o texto acima igual ao texto abaixo.</h3>
<div class="post">
    <p>kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk<br>kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nesse caso ele não possui espaço e mesmo assim adiciona o <br>, você precisa quebrar quando chegar em determinada quantidade ?

Comment: O objetivo é mesmo adicionar a tag `<br>` ou apenas "quebrar" a palavra para a linha seguinte?

Comment: Olá Jonas, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que teve várias perguntas fechadas recentemente. Recomendo que leia o guia [ask] para aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eu particularmente não utilizaria `js` ou `php` para fazer isso, você poderia resolver a quebra de linha apenas usando `word-wrap:break-word` do `css`, assim:

```css
.post {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #e1e8ed;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <p>kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</p>
</div>
```

Veja a compatibilidade: [Can I use?](http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap)

Comment: Exatamente, era isso que eu estava para dizer :)

Comment: perfeito, obrigado.

Comment: demais mesmo...

Comment: nunca tinha visto essa propriedade no css

Answer (score 2):

Uma coisa assim?

```
$(function() {
   var total = $('.post p:first').html().length;
    var line_brk = (total < 69) ? 69 : (total / 2);
    var el = $('.post p:first');
    var data = el.html();
    var t = '';
    for(var i in data) {
         t += data[i];
        if(i == line_brk) {
           t +='<br>';
        }
    }
    el.html(t);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode obter o conteúdo do elemento `<p>`, e a partir dele "quebrar" o texto baseado na sua lógica. Por exemplo, o código abaixo adiciona o `<br>` quando o texto é maior que um certo tamanho, mas você pode mudar a condição para quando o texto não tem espaços. Note que o código pode ser simplificado (bastante) com bibliotecas tais como jQuery, mas a idéia é a mesma.

```
var postDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("post")[0];
var pElem = null;
for (var i = 0; i < postDiv.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var child = postDiv.childNodes[i];
    if (child.nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE && child.localName === "p") {
        pElem = child;
        break;
    }
}
var textSizeLimit = 69;
var pText = pElem.innerText;
if (pText.length > textSizeLimit) {
    while (pElem.hasChildNodes()) {
        pElem.removeChild(pElem.firstChild);
    }

    do {
        var lineText = pText.substring(0, textSizeLimit);
        pElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lineText));

        pText = pText.substring(textSizeLimit);
        if (pText.length > 0) {
            pElem.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    } while (pText.length > 0);
}
```

Comment: poderia editar para usar em toda div com a class post?

Comment: Sim, em vez de pegar o primeiro elemento (`getElementsByClassName("post")[0]), você pode pegar todos os elementos e iterar sobre eles.