# Quebrar linha corretamente em uma Lista com Data Binding AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Tenho uma lista de comentários onde exibo alguns dados. Porém quando o comentário é muito grande a lista fica estranha pois a quebra de linhas não acontece corretamente.

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div layout="row" layout-margin>
    <div flex="40">
      <p>Comentários</p>
    </div>
    <div flex="30">
      <md-button type="file" class="md-raised md-primary" style="width:100%;margin-left: 115%;margin-top: -1px;" data-toggle="modal" 
      data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
        Novo Comentário</md-button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </br>
</br>
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="comentario in comentarios">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <b>{{comentario.usuario.login}}</b><i class="fa fa-comment" style="margin-left: 40px;" ></i>{{comentario.comentario}}
    <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="margin-left: 50px;"></i>{{comentario.dataComentario | date: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Como posso arrumar essa lista?

**OBS:** Estou fazendo `CSS` *Inline* para testes.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Preciso de uma função para adicionar <br> em certas condições](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95429/preciso-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-adicionar-br-em-certas-condi%c3%a7%c3%b5es)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ajustar altura da div conforme o texto?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5302/como-ajustar-altura-da-div-conforme-o-texto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando o atributo css `word-break: break-all;` você consegue quebrar as linhas do comentário.

[Can i use word-break?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break)

Referência: [MDN - word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de apenas inserir o seu dado diretamente no seu `<i>` , você poderia criar um div, e pré-determinar seu tamanho, feito isto poderia utilizar um javascript para contar o tamanho do textos sendo assim ao exceder esse valor fosse inserido uma tag

```
if(meutexto.length > 25)
{
  $('.minhalinha').append("<br>");
}
```

Esta seria uma alternativa para conseguir realizar essa quebra de texto.

Comment: Essa verificação não é uma forma adequada de fazer isso. Imagine se tiver muitos comentários? Tela de diferentes resoluções?

Comment: De fato, mas ao meu ver está seria a forma mais simples, que pode ser facilmente manipulada por media querys e alguns "ifs" de verificação do width