# Como fazer quebra de linha em uma <li>?

Tags: html, css, quebras-de-linha

**Como faço para dar uma quebra de linha em um texto que esta dentro de uma li, e configurar css pra ficar correto?**

Estou a tentar fazer um menu cujo os list itens têm fundo quadrangular, mas eu até consigo fazer a quebra de linha mas o problema é no CSS que não estou a conseguir configurar, e da erro e fica todo atrapalhado, e isto me impossibilita de fazer tal ato, gostaria que vocês me ajudassem por favor.

Comment: já tentou a propriedade css word-wrap:

Comment: cadê o código? Posta o codigo, não da para gente imaginar como deve ser.

Comment: Relacionados:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5302/como-ajustar-altura-da-div-conforme-o-texto  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95429/preciso-de-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-adicionar-br-em-certas-condi%C3%A7%C3%B5es/95436#95436

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi direito sua pergunta, tenta colocar o código, mas até aonde eu entendi, seria o caso apenas de um `</br>`

> dar uma quebra de linha em um texto que esta dentro de uma li

No HTML no ponto onde você quer dar a quebra de linha e coloca `</br>`